# Redux share state between screens for async data

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a simple application with 3 routes. (using react-router)

Overview, Invitations, Settings.

Overview Page -  shows overview data, but some data is related for invitations.

Invitations Page - show data only on invitations.

So i think to structure my redux state for share data:

```
{
    ...
    invitations: []
    ...
}
```

and then i can get the invitations data in Overview/Invitations page as well.

If you visit first on Overview/Invitations I have to fetch invitations data and update reducer, but if user navigate between pages Overview/Invitations i don't want to fetch data again.

so what is the best practice to handle this.

1) share data between screens? or store data for each screen?

2) if share, what is the practice for this case?

Comment: You may need to provide more context, e.g., how are you routing? If you're not doing anything in particular for routing the state is just there.

Comment: react-router and i update the post, thanks!

Comment: You must think about some use cases. What if the user wants to fetch data again? Will the user change the page and go back to refresh it? You will have specific buttons / conditions to update the data after it is loaded the first time? Is it possible that you will use too much memory on the client after the user navigates through several pages?